# LINQ Expression cannot be translated - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I wrote simple query (issues is when I try to set an `Address` below `ProductCode`):

```
 var query = _connectDBContext.Products
                            .Join(_context.CustomerRelations,
                                Product => Product.ForeignKeyId,
                                CustomerRelation => CustomerRelation.CompanyId,
                                (Product, CustomerRelation) => new { Product, CustomerRelation })
                            .Select(x => new ProductDto
                            {
                                Title = x.Product.Title,
                                ProductCode = x.Product.Code,
                                Address = Map(x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x=> x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()),
                                //Address = new AddressDTO // THIS WORKS BUT LOOKS UGLY :(
                                //{
                                //    Address = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Address,
                                //    Country = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Country,
                                //    Zip = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Zip,
                                //},
                               
                            })
                            .Where(x => x.Id == x.CustomerRelationId);

           // Rest of the code
        }

private AddressDTO Map(Address address)
{
    return new AddressDTO
    {
        Address = address.Address,
        Country = address.Country,
        Zip = address.Zip,

    };
}
```

This code above breaks on this line:

```
Address = Map(x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x=> x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()),
```

It says that linq cannot be translated and advicing me to rewrite a query..

But this commented code here which does almost the same **works**, so if I remove calling **Map** method in **Select** and if I uncomment this code in **Select** everything would work, but I would like to get rid of this - writing too many `OrderBy` for each prop, I would like to Order it once and after that I would like to use it.. but unfortunatelly I don't know how.. :

```
//Address = new AddressDTO 
//{
//    Address = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Address,
//    Country = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Country,
//    Zip = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Zip,
//},
```

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Comment: You can't call `Map` from your query as EF doesn't know how to translate that to SQL. Maybe restructure it to return your data first (perhaps use an anonymous object for the Address property), and then call `Map` once you have your data back from the database.

Comment: @MatthewLayton Thanks for fast response Matthew! May you please provide some kind of example so I might try do it right now? How could I solve it with anonymous object for the Address property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably Entity Framework is translating this code to SQL, and your custom `Map()` method is unknown to SQL.  Fortunately that method doesn't do much, so you should be able to move its functionality directly to the query.

You can use `.Select()` to project the collection into a new type (just like you already do for building your `ProductDto`).

For example:

```
//...
Address = x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x=> x.CreatedDate)
                             .Select(x=> new AddressDTO
                             {
                                 Address = x.Address,
                                 Country = x.Country,
                                 Zip = x.Zip
                             })
                             .FirstOrDefault()
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

See David's answer above for explanation why it does not work.

For a workaround, you can call .ToList() before the mapping so the query is executed on the server:

```
_connectDBContext.Products
  .Join(...)
  .Where(x => x.Id == x.CustomerRelationId)
  .ToList() // !!!
  .Select(x => new ProductDto
     {
        Title = x.Product.Title,
        ProductCode = x.Product.Code,
        Address = Map(x.Product.Addresses.OrderBy(x=> x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()),
...
     });
```

Comment: But that means, that all `Products` plus joined data will be put into your memory. `ToList()` is a performance killer!

Comment: true, not optimal. this is why you move the Where clause before the ToList to limit the number of results early. you need to understand what is happening and what are the consequences. for small result set is OK, for larger number of items - need to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the Map function as it is, but you can modify it a bit to work on Queryables instead

```cs
var query = _connectDBContext.Products
                            .Join(_context.CustomerRelations,
                                Product => Product.ForeignKeyId,
                                CustomerRelation => CustomerRelation.CompanyId,
                                (Product, CustomerRelation) => new { Product, CustomerRelation })
                            .Select(x => new ProductDto
                            {
                                Title = x.Product.Title,
                                ProductCode = x.Product.Code,
                                Address = Map(x.Product.Addresses),
                               
                            })
                            .Where(x => x.Id == x.CustomerRelationId);

           // Rest of the code
        }

private AddressDTO Map(IQueryable<Address> addresses)
{
    return addresses.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(x => new AddressDTO
    {
        Address = address.Address,
        Country = address.Country,
        Zip = address.Zip
    }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```